# pgr_astar function does not accept negative values?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, astar

I'm using postgreSQL and I'm running the `pgr_astar` function to get the optimal path. I calculated my path using a formula that uses angle of elevation or the angle of depression as input. So I'm getting negative values on the cost column, I `pgr_astr` function does not return any result when I'm using the cost values.

Any suggestion please? How can I manipulate this function to get the optimal path using the cost's negative values?

Comment: What if you just add a constant for making all values positive? If zero cost means that you reach the target in no time then what would negative cost mean?

Comment: Thank you for commenting, a negative value represent a fuel consumption of a down hill where the fuel consumed is -value from the fuel consumption of a flat segment.

Comment: Calculate some other measure that is always positive. Like absolute fuel consumption (liters/km) or relational (90 percent of the consumption on flat).